# how to undo a wrongly performed query which affected the records in SQL

Tags: sql

I added a new column to already existed Table

```
alter table Employee
add  Emp_dept varchar(50)
```

try to insert columns in to table now but output was not as  i was expected

```
insert into Employee(Emp_dept)
values ('Accounting'),
('Accounting'),
('Technical'),
('Technical'),
('Managing'),
('Managing');
```

Comment: It depends on a lot of things. What RDBMS are you using? What was your output and what did you want it to be?

Comment: You can wipe the existing data in that column using `UPDATE Employee SET emp_dept IS NULL`.

Comment: You are looking for an `UPDATE` statement not an `INSERT`. Please read a SQL tutorial. This is basic SQL knowledge.

Comment: yaa thanks for ur advices and iam at starting stages of learning sql

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you began with a table:

```
Employee
+----+-------+
| ID | Name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | Joe   |
|  2 | Bob   |
|  3 | Mary  |
+----+-------+
```

Then applied the ALTER TABLE, you probably obtained:

```
Employee
+----+-------+----------+
| ID | Name  | Emp_dept |
+----+-------+----------+
|  1 | Joe   |     NULL |
|  2 | Bob   |     NULL |
|  3 | Mary  |     NULL |
+----+-------+----------+
```

If you then performed the insert, and it worked at all, I expect you would then have something like:

```
Employee
+----+-------+------------+
| ID | Name  |   Emp_dept |
+----+-------+------------+
|  1 | Joe   |       NULL |
|  2 | Bob   |       NULL |
|  3 | Mary  |       NULL |
|  4 | NULL  | Accounting |
|  5 | NULL  | Accounting |
|  6 | NULL  | Technical  |
|  7 | NULL  | Technical  |
|  8 | NULL  | Managing   |
|  9 | NULL  | Managing   |
+----+-------+------------+
```

Here I've assumed that `ID` is an autoincrement column and `Name` is `NULL`able.

To reverse this, you could try:

```
DELETE FROM Employee WHERE Emp_dept IS NOT NULL
```

Followed by:

```
ALTER TABLE Employee DROP COLUMN Emp_dept
```

This should return you to where you were prior to adding the column, which appears to be what you want.